# Spark goes java heap space out of memory with a small collect

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I've got a problem with Spark, its driver and an OoM issue.

Currently I have a dataframe which is being built with several, joined sources (actually different tables in parquet format), and there are thousands of tuples. They have a date which represents the date of creation of the record, and distinctly they are a few.

I do the following:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import year, month

# ...

selectionRows = inputDataframe.select(year('registration_date').alias('year'), month('registration_date').alias('month')).distinct()
selectionRows.show() # correctly shows 8 tuples
selectionRows = selectionRows.collect() # goes heap space OoM
print(selectionRows)
```

Reading the memory consumption statistics shows that the driver does not exceed ~60%. I thought that the driver should load only the distinct subset, not the entire dataframe.

Am I missing something? Is it possible to collect those few rows in a smarter way? I need them as a pushdown predicate to load a secondary dataframe.

Thank you very much!

**EDIT / SOLUTION**

After reading the comments and elaborating my personal needs, I cached the dataframe at every "join/elaborate" step, so that in a timeline I do the following:

- Join with loaded table
- Queue required transformations
- Apply the cache transformation
- Print the count to keep track of cardinality (mainly for tracking / debugging purposes) and thus apply all transformations + cache
- Unpersist the cache of the previous sibiling step, if available (tick/tock paradigm)

This reduced some complex ETL jobs down to 20% of the original time (as previously it was applying the transformations of each previous step at each count).

Lesson learned :)

Comment: you mentioned that the data is being created using many tables joined together. One thing you could try is checkpointing or caching some key dataframes. E.G., in your exmaple, you could cache `SelectionRows` before the `.show()`, and then use the dataframe to `collect()`. also, you should try to avoid `df = df.collect()`

Comment: You might be able to avoid the collect completely - if selectionRows is an "IN" list just join it with the secondary DataFrame, if it's a "NOT IN" list you can use the left anti join to filter those matches out. If you really do need to collect, caching it may help since as written that code actually processes the data twice.

Comment: Interesting. So caching allows you to kind of remember all the things elaborated so far? Would that increase performance if I cache the result of a data frame series of transformations made at each table join? For example I might have 10 tables to join and make operations after the join of each of them. If I do not cache, the operations will be made every time I do a count, or a collect for instance, unless I cache the data frame at that state?

Comment: you'd have to cache it at smart points. theoretically, yes, it increases performance because it stores the underlying output of the dataframe in its memory. but your memory won't always be enough to store the dataframe's output - so it gets spilled to disk and the process reads it back from there whenever required. Reading from disk is of course slower than reading it from in-memory caches. Also, remember that the dataframe is cached after it's first action (e.g., `collect()`, `count()`, `show()`). Simply running the `cache()` code does not cache it.

Comment: Thanks @samkart - indeed caching improved the execution exponentially (we used to count after each join and post-join elaborations to keep track of cardinality). I now cache the DF just before the count() and unpersist the previous cache (of the previous join). Thank you very much :)

Comment: If you've found your solution, please put it below in the answer section rather than edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comments, I elaborated the solution for my use case.

As mentioned in the question, I join several tables one with each other in a "target dataframe", and at each iteration I do some transformations, like so:

```py
# n-th table work
target = target.join(other, how='left')
target = target.filter(...)
target = target.withColumn('a', 'b')
target = target.select(...)
print(f'Target after table "other": {target.count()}')
```

The problem of slowliness / OoM was that Spark was forced to do all the transformations from start to finish at each table due to the ending `count`, making it slower and slower at each table / iteration.

The solution I found is to cache the dataframe at each iteration, like so:

```py
cache: DataFrame = null

# ...

# n-th table work
target = target.join(other, how='left')
target = target.filter(...)
target = target.withColumn('a', 'b')
target = target.select(...)

target = target.cache()
target_count = target.count() # actually do the cache
if cache:
  cache.unpersist() # free the memory from the old cache version
cache = target

print(f'Target after table "other": {target_count}')
```